# Python import the database from the .gz file

Tags: python, mysql, sql, docker

I work with a tool where I get the database dump for the MySQL and the Postgresql in the `.gz` compressed file. This is the file I have exported earlier seamlessly (using python). However, when I need to test for the importing, this doesn't work.

The tool work inside the docker container. My python code is provided,

```
def cmd_schema_import(self, args=None):


    self.require_configured(with_containers=True)
    compressed_import_file = os.path.join(self.project_path, "database", config['database_backup'])

    # no file exist for the database import
    if (not os.path.isfile(compressed_import_file)):
        return

    # run mysql dump
    u, p, d = config['default_db_user'], config['default_db_pass'], config['default_db_name']
    command = f'mysqldump -u {u} -p"{p}" {d}'

    if self.project_conf["db_driver"] == "pgsql":
        command = f'exec psql --quiet -U {u} -d "{d}"'

    additional_options = "| gunzip < %s --keep" % compressed_import_file
    self.docker.exec(self.db_container, command, additional_options)
```

The function calls a docker method provided,

```
def exec(self, container_target, command, additional_options=""):
    """ execte docker exec commmand and return the stdout or None when error"""
    cmd = """docker exec -i "%s" sh -c '%s' %s""" % (
        container_target, command, additional_options)
    if self.verbose:
        print(cmd)
    try:
        cp = subprocess.run(cmd,
                            shell=True,
                            check=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        return cp.stdout.decode("utf-8").strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Docker exec failed command {e}")
        return None
```

I try to debug the code but this is where it gets hung,

```
cp = subprocess.run(cmd,
                            shell=True,
                            check=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I appreciate any advise.

Comment: What do you mean `this doesn't work`? What's error?

Comment: I mentioned "I try to debug the code but this is where it gets hung"

Comment: Did you try to execute what ends up in `cmd` at that line on the command line? I'd suspect that the command you end up with isn't exactly what you had in mind.

Comment: @bgse you are right and with docker, there is a lot better option to do it. We can mount the SQL file from the host to the container and they will be in sync. I think there is no point for me to hang up with the `.gz` file.